# How to do query by example on ONLY ONE nested attributes?

Tags: arangodb

So I'm using ArangoDB and got a nested data structure like the following:

```
doc 1 = { "a" : {
    "uid": 1,
    "properties":{ 
       "meta": 0
       }
    }
}

doc 2 = { "a" : {
    "uid": 1,
    "properties":{}
    }
}
```

I want to be able to fetch all document where `uid` is `1` without having to take in account the properties attribute's value.

Doing a fetch by example with `{ "a" : { "uid": 1 } }` return nothing.

Comment: By "fetch by example", do you mean in Arangosh, using the deprecated Simple Query interface?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming doc1 and doc2 are documents saved in a document collection `docs`, you can access all documents with uid=1 by filtering on the subattribute `a.uid`.

AQL example:

```
FOR doc IN docs FILTER doc.a.uid==1 RETURN doc
```